# Connection terminated when I do POST request?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, postman

I am wondering if anyone can help me out here. I'm currently taking a Udemy course on learning how to connect a database with my server. I have been going word by word on the teacher's code, frequently checking if my code has any minor errors. I didn't have any trouble with code thus far on my server.js file. Port is running smoothly. However, when I run the POST request from Postman, I get

> Unhandled rejection Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly

Through Postman, I am following exactly what the teacher did. The POST request contains email, password, name and the localhost:3000/register path is fine. That is what my server is connected to. I'm wondering what's going on since my code runs smoothly until I do a POST request. Also noting that I get 200 OK response on Postman but on server, I get that unhandled rejection error message.

[image]

Yeah that console log is intentional, I am going along exactly what he is doing in the video so code is bound to change over time on the next video.

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require ('bcrypt-nodejs');
const cors = require('cors');
const knex = require('knex');
const pg = require('pg');

const db = knex({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    user : 'postgres',
    port: '3000',
    password : '',
    database : 'smart-brain'
  }
});




const app = express();

const database = {
  users: [
    {
      id: '123',
      name: 'Jess',
      email: 'jess@gmail.com',
      password: 'cookies',
      entries: 0,
      joined: new Date()
    },
     {
      id: '124',
      name: 'Sally',
      email: 'sally@gmail.com',
      password: 'bananas',
      entries: 0,
      joined: new Date()
    }
  ]
}


app.use(bodyParser.json());
//body parser is basically json.parse. we want to always parse json so our code is readable in string form. POST > Raw > JSON
app.use(cors())

app.get('/', (req, res)=> {
        res.send(database.users);
        })

app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
  if(req.body.email === database.users[0].email && req.body.password === database.users[0].password) {
    res.json(database.users[0])
  } else {
    res.status(400).json('error logging in')
  }
})

app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const { email, name, password } = req.body;
  db('users').insert({
    email: email,
    name: name,
    joined: new Date() 
  }).then(() => console.log())
  res.json(database.users[database.users.length-1])
});


app.get('/profile/:id', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  let found = false;
  database.users.forEach(user => {
    if (user.id === id) {
      found = true;
      return res.json(user);
    } 
  })
  if (!found) {
    res.status(400).json('not found...')
  }
})

//now we are creating route for entries count. everytime they submit image, they will get a count for it
app.put('/image', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body;
  let found = false;
  database.users.forEach(user => {
    if (user.id === id) {
      found = true;
      user.entries++
      return res.json(user.entries);
    } 
  })
  if (!found) {
    res.status(400).json('not found...')
  }
})

app.listen(3000, ()=> {
  console.log('app is running on port 3000');
})
```

Comment: The code in your screenshot differs to the code in your question. Which is correct?

Comment: @Phil The code on the bottom is just the entire code in my javascript file, just posting that in case anyone finds errors that I've neglected to look over. Sorry, I should have circled the code that I had trouble with the most. In the app.post('/register'-- portion, I had the most trouble. I was following along in the video with that code and still got the error through the server.

Answer (score 0):

try to add catch function after then block.

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
const { email, name, password } = req.body;
  db('users').insert({
    email: email,
    name: name,
    joined: new Date() 
  }).then(() => {
    res.json(database.users[database.users.length-1])   
  }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})

});
```

Comment: check the error logs in this case and resolve accordingly.

Comment: Hm yeah it's odd. Now that I did the .catch function and did POST request, Postman just hangs and doesn't send the request thru. Must be a fetch problem but looking it over, the route is completely fine.

Comment: are you seeing any error on your server side logs `console.log(err)`

Comment: Yeah for sure when it comes to server side, many errors.
node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:200:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\cygwin64\home\jyin9\onedrive\desktop\smart-brain-api\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:130:10)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.

Comment: unless you resolve these error there is no point of send `res.json(database.users[database.users.length-1])` that's why we put this statement in then block only.